# Unity JSON Saving not writing certain variables correctly

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

This is a save and load system we're developing for our multiplayer game. We are using Mirror for networking.

File Handler Code (Only Saving Part)

```
public void Save(GameData data, string profileId)
{
    // use Path.Combine to account for different OS's having different path separators
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(dataDirPath, profileId, dataFileName);
    try
    {
        // create the directory the file will be written to if it doesn't already exist
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath));

        // serialize the C# game data object into Json
        string dataToStore = JsonUtility.ToJson(data, true);

        // optionally encrypt the data
        if (useEncryption)
        {
            dataToStore = EncryptDecrypt(dataToStore);
        }

        // write the serialized data to the file
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(dataToStore);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error occured when trying to save data to file: " + fullPath + "\n" + e);
    }
```

Data Persistence Manager (Only Saving)

```
public void SaveGame()
{
    // pass the data to other scripts so they can update it
    foreach (IDataPersistence dataPersistenceObj in dataPersistenceObjects)
    {
        dataPersistenceObj.SaveData(gameData);
    }

    // save that data to a file using the data handler
    dataHandler.Save(gameData, selectedProfileId);
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    SaveGame();
}
```

The problem we've encountered is regarding saving certain variables, loading works perfectly fine both in multiplayer and single player.

This part of the code is for saving each item of the players inventory. It checks each slot and then saves the item ID into an array of integers. In single player this works perfectly fine. However, in multiplayer when the clients data is saved it does not write the inventory slots integers, they are always defaulted to 0. Which is the default in the constructor for the game data.

```
public void SaveData(GameData data)
    {
        Debug.Log("In Save");     
        for (int i = 0; i < 39; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("In Save 2");
            if (inventory.slots[i].item == null)
            {
                data.inventoryItemIdArray[i] = 0;
                data.inventoryItemCountArray[i] = 0;
                Debug.Log("In Save No Item");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("In Save Item");
                Debug.Log("SAVE SLOT ITEM IS: " + inventory.slots[i].item.id);
                data.inventoryItemIdArray[i] = this.inventory.slots[i].item.id;
                data.inventoryItemCountArray[i] = this.inventory.slots[i].count;
            }          
        }  
    }
```

Currently this has no multiplayer implementation because we believe it does not need it, the data file is created on each of the players games and the saving and loading operates independently, the worlds data runs off of the hosts data file.

Now what really stumped us is this test implementation of saving on a coin, in both multiplayer and single player this works fine. The inventory saving theoretically works the same way yet it doesn't work, there's only a few differences and we cannot seem to figure out what's causing it to not work.

```
public void SaveData(GameData data)
    {
        data.coins = this.coins;
    }
```

- We have tried logging the lines of code to see if it is actually running it or not, it is.
- We have tried using several different int variables instead of an array, thinking that the array was the problem. It didn't work, same problem.
- We have tried calling the `SaveGame()` function manually (is currently in `OnApplicationQuit()`)
- offhandedly we changed `inventory.slots[i].item.id` to `this.inventory.slots[i].item.id` hoping it would do something, since it was one of the few differences with the coin example that worked. It didn't work
- I logged the value of the integer its trying to save, thinking maybe it was null and that's why it seems to not work, it wasn't null.

*Edit
Game Data Code

```
// variables to be saved
public int coins;
public Vector3 playerPosition;
public SerializableDictionary<string, bool> resourceCollected;
public int[] inventoryItemIdArray = new int[39];
public int[] inventoryItemCountArray = new int[39];

public int bodyPartID;
public int torsoPartID;
public int legsPartID;



// value defined in this constructor will be the default value (null? whetever they are set to initially)
public GameData()
{
    this.coins = 0;
    playerPosition = Vector3.zero;
    resourceCollected = new SerializableDictionary<string, bool>();
    inventoryItemIdArray = new int[39];
    inventoryItemCountArray = new int[39];
}
```

The array being printed, the first value is '1' which i manually changed in the file to add an "axe" to my inventory.

```
"inventoryItemIdArray": [
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
],
```

Comment: So you are saying even though you can print the exact item id it is somehow `null` in the next line? Have you looked at the complete Array that you are reading out? There has to be some fundamental flaw

Comment: [**Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Show us your code for the `GameData` type!

Comment: Btw it is extremely dangerous to put this into `ApplicationQuit` .. on certain platforms (e.g. HoloLens) there is no guarantee this is called at all and if your user closes the app or it crashes progress is completely lost ;)

Comment: @derHugo Hi
I've removed the images as advised
I've also added the code for the GameData class and in regards to ApplicationQuit, we will definitively change it soon!
Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Roe I've added the array its printed out, i have to manually change the array in the file to add items to my inventory, hence the "1". No matter what other items the slots contain the array will always print 0 in multiplayer for the client only. I'm sure there's a flaw somewhere i just can't find it.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: @boyspeak couple things I find "weird":  1; filling the array based on index without knowing the slot at the index is actually the correct slot (no identifier). 2; inconsistency in what you log and try to input into the array (I assume this is equal in your code but that is not visible to us). 3. Where does `inventory` come from is it your custom type, what does it look like?

Comment: I am with @Roe .. it seems a bit weird / error prone to have to synchronize two places where the data is stored ... why not stick to your slots and serialize those directly? Having two independent arrays and having to synchronize those seems unnecessary .. why not rather use a single array with a proper serializable data type like your slots? (and just fyi the `this` is most of the time optional as it is implicit anyway .. you only require it in case of a parameter with same name which hides the class fields)

Comment: Also you claiming that it works perfectly fine in single but not in multiplayer means there is rather an issue about what happens differently in multiplayer .. not in the serialization itself (even as said it is quite weird) ... => What is multiplayer doing differently? How is the data synchronized here, saved and how is it loaded again and where exactly is it lost => [Debug your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)